# Dependency Inject exposition and DependencyResolver in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a service (AccountService) which has around eight methods. One of these methods sends an email. I have another service (EmailService) which is constructor injected into the AccountService.

I was wondering whether it's necessary to do this because it feels like every time I add functionality with a dependency to a method I have to change all my tests where I'm mocking up the dependencies for the constructor. This feels like DI is actually making it harder to change things, rather than easier.

So I was thinking about using the DependencyResolver in my controller action which calls the AccountService to get hold of the EmailService and pass it in. However, will this affect my tests?

How would I go about testing the controller action that used the dependency resolver? Given that the account service is constructor injected by ninject into the AccountController.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the DependencyResolver in your Controller! Just use it to create the controller using Ninject (See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki). Everything else should be created by Ninject using constructor injection.

Actually, Unit Testing with proper DI and a design that follows the SOLID principles is quite easy.

In the test fixture setup you do nothing else than creating a (dynamic) mock for each dependency and an instance of the object under test using the created mocks as dependencies. That way you have to call the constructor exactly once for all your tests for each class.

If testing is hard it's not because of DI but rather by either not following the SOLID principles (most likely the single responsibility principle) or because of bad tests e.g. Unittests that use real instances of dependencies rather than mocks or doing too much in your test fixture setup.

Comment: You're probably right on the tests, should I be setting up the mocks as fields in my test fixtures so that I can add functionality to them? Occasionally I'll use fakes e.g. InMemoryRepository<Product> rather than Mock<IRepository<Product>>. It's not that things are hard to test, it's just because I tend to try and make tests atomic so all the set up is in each case. I'll review my services for SRP and try and move the initialisation of the class being tested out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Property DI or is it necessary to inject it into the .ctor?
BTW:for your tests are you using somekind of Mocking Framework (e.g. Moq, RhinoMocks)?

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Property injection should be avoided unless the dependency is optional and the service can life without it.